# python win32com Causes Program crash

Tags: python, com, itunes, py2exe

I wrote program to control iTunes by monitoring keystrokes from with pyHooks and then interfaceing with the iTunes COM interface.

The program works fine, the only problem I have is when I try to compile it with py2exe. The program always crashes with this traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.pyc", line 527, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "iTunesControl.py", line 24, in run
  File "win32com\client\gencache.pyc", line 540, in EnsureDispatch
  File "win32com\client\CLSIDToClass.pyc", line 46, in GetClass
KeyError: '{9DD6680B-3EDC-40DB-A771-E6FE4832E34A}'

py2exe reports no errors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably that the py2exe version isn't able to access the cache of wrappers generated by win32com.

[Here's a recipe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/UsingEnsureDispatch) for dealing with this problem.